# Add SVG title to plotly chart before downloading PNG

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, plotly

I have a Javascript Plotly chart without a title which I offer for downloading PNG image. The image should have a title, so I try to add it to the SVG tree just before downloading it:

```
  d3.select(".main-svg .draglayer")
    .append("svg:text")
      .attr("id", "svgtitle")
      .attr("x", 50)             
      .attr("y", 50)
      .attr("text-anchor", "left")  
      .style("font-size", "26px") 
      .style("fill", "#FF0000") 
      .style("font-weight", "bold")
      .text("My chart");
```

The idea is to remove the title after downloading the image by something like `svg.remove("#svgtitle")`;

I used d3js select and append as I additionally use this library for painting some maps on my site, but it should be the same using plain Javascript like that:

```
var title = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", 'text');
title.setAttribute("x", 20);
...
```

To show the not desired behavior I made a [Code Pen](https://codepen.io/gkogler/pen/PoZGZoJ) based on the official Plotly [Basic Bar Chart Example](https://plotly.com/javascript/bar-charts/#basic-bar-chart).

What am I doing wrong, or is there an easier way to add an element only visible for export but not on screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple, but you need to take into account the difference between the `DOM` and the `gd` object. Everything you change on `.main-svg` affects the `DOM`, but not the `plotly` object. In your code, to change the object you need to act on `gd`.

According to the documentation, the `title` is inside a structure called `layout`. Therefore, you can set it with `javascript` at any time. In your code, you can draw the chart without a title (`Plotly.plot()`), then change the title (`gd.layout.title`) and then download the PNG. The title structure has several keys for the text and font features. You can see a demo [here](https://codepen.io/vqf/pen/oNbzYoM). I removed the title you had set in the `DOM`.